# Why sending messages through JMX in Apache Camel disabled?

Tags: apache-camel

Why sending messages through JMX in Apache Camel disabled?

How it looks with JConsole:

[image]
[image]

How can I enable access to this function through JMX?

Apache Camel version - 2.21.1

Route Spring DSL:

```
<camelContext id="cameltest001" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" trace="true">
    <route id="1">
        <from uri="timer:test?fixedRate=true&amp;delay=1000" id="timer"/>
        <to uri="mock:result" id="mockend"/>
        <to uri="log:test" />
    </route>

    <route id="2">
        <from uri="direct:2"/>
        <to uri="mock:result" id="mockend2"/>
        <to uri="log:test" />
    </route>

</camelContext>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not disabled in Apache Camel, but JConsole allows to invoke only operations with simple type or primitive arguments. `Object` is not simple type and JConsole does not know how to construct `p2` argument instance.

If your route consumes `String` (or type, which can be converted from `String` by TypeConverters), use `sendStringBody(String, String)` operation instead of `sendBody(String, Object)`.

Comment: Thank you. It's very helpful answer!